# function has 2 arguments but error says 0 given

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I'm getting an error back that says the function needs 2 arguments and none are given. I thought I had given the getBanner function 2 arguments where it's used in the main function.

```
import socket

def getBanner2(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except Exception, e:
        print "[!] " + str(e)
        getBanner2()

def main():
    #ip1 = raw_input('Enter IP > ')
    #port = int(raw_input('Enter Port > '))

    ip1 = '10.10.0.115'
    port = 22

    banner1 = getBanner2(ip1, port)

    if banner1:
        print '[+] ' + ip1 + ': ' + banner1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getBanner2.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "./getBanner2.py", line 26, in main
    banner1 = getBanner2(ip1, port)
  File "./getBanner2.py", line 17, in getBanner2
    getBanner2()
TypeError: getBanner2() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: You should always post the full error message (including the stack trace)

Comment: Ok. So I added the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getBanner2` function, you have called `getBanner2()` again without the arguments in the Exception block.

```
def getBanner2(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except Exception, e:
        print "[!] " + str(e)
        getBanner2(ip, port) # changed
```

Carefully analyze the traceback, as most of the time, it's enough to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I had it working and I added something I couldn't remember and I guess that's it. Thanx. ^^

Comment: @user7526725 this is pretty clearly laid out in the error message. It even tells you the exact line: `line 17, in getBanner2`

Comment: Aye. I just wanted to make it go back to the start. I added while True: main() at the end. That's what I was going for.

Comment: Ok. Do you need any help with that ?